# Execute string as a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, eval

I am trying to build a line of code to dynamically change the function name, by doing this I am storing the name of each function in a variable (to grab from an html element, not important). Either way, what I am trying to do is this:

```
var validateType = $this.data("type");

new Validator.validateType($this.val(), validateLength)
```

Validator is an object, then ofcourse "validateType" is the name of each subfunction in that object.
"validateType" is also the variable.

I am getting this for an error: `TypeError: validator.validateType is not a function`

I have tried:

```
 new Validator.window[validateType]($this.val(), validateLength)
```

But it doesn't work, it says: `TypeError: Validator.window is undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ['bracket' notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation). Since you said `Validator` is an object and not a constructor function, you don't need to use [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

Try this:

```
Validator[validateType]($this.val(), validateLength)
```